# ServiceNow / GlideRecord - how to prepare data for chart after query the table?

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, servicenow

i am trying to build a visualization in a dynamic content block to be used in dashboards.
i m using d3.js as chart library. it already looks like expected but i only use hard-coded data and i'd like to query tables for realtime data.

this is what i did so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">  
<html>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .chart rect {
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        .chart text {
            fill: white;
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            text-anchor: start;
        }

        .centered-chart {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="centered-chart">
            <h1>D3 Chart Test - Incidents (Priority) </h1>
            <svg class="chart"></svg>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>

        var c = this;


        var data = [
        
        {"category": "1 - Critical", "value": 26}, 
        {"category": "2 - High", "value": 4}, 
        {"category": "3 - Moderate", "value": 8}, 
        {"category": "4 - Low", "value": 3},
        {"category": "5 - Planning", "value": 14}
        
        ];


        var width = 600,

        barHeight = 20;



        var chart = d3.select(".chart")

        .attr("width", width)

        .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);




        var x = d3.scaleLinear()

        .range([0, width])

        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);




        var bar = chart.selectAll("g")

        .data(data)

        .enter().append("g")

        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });




        bar.append("rect")

        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })

        .attr("height", barHeight - 1);




        bar.append("text")

        .attr("x", 5)

        .attr("y", barHeight / 2)

        .attr("dy", ".35em")

        .text(function(d) { return d.category; });



        bar.append("text")

        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 15; })

        .attr("y", barHeight / 2)

        .attr("dy", ".35em")

        .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
    </script>
</html>
</j:jelly>
```

but as mentioned earlier i only use hard-coded data :(

so, i did some testing like this:

```
<script>
    var gr = new GlideRecord('incident');
        gr.addQuery('priority', '=', 1);
        gr.query(response);

    function response(result) {
        while(result.next()) {
            console.log(result.getValue('number')); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

just to see if this query thing does its job but i am not really familiar with SNow scripting or gliderecord to understand or get an idea, how i get this incidents in priority groups or count them, i mean
how do i prepare the data, so that i am able to use it in my chart like the hardcoded data?

i know, this is a really simple scenario and its just for me to understand basics and get deeper into this but i am running already into problems at this early stage and i hope anyone has an idea how to go on or can give me some tips about logic in this thing.

so, i hope you all got a good start into this week and someone has a better understanding of what i am trying to do and could give me some advice.

greetz
dennis

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `ServiceNow` or `GlideRecord`, so I hope I can help.

Your question isn't specifically related to d3, since you know how to get data from one format into a visualisation, but more related to how to get it from GlideRecord to said format.

```js
   var categories = {
      1: "1 - Critical",
      2: "2 - High",
      3: "3 - Moderate",
      4: "4 - Low"
      5: "5 - Planning"
    };

    var data = [];
    var gr = new GlideRecord('incident');

    // Object.entries returns sets of (key, value)
    Object.entries(categories).forEach(function(entry) {
      var priority = entry[0];
      var category = entry[1];
      gr.addQuery('priority', '=', priority);

      // getRowCount returns the number of matching rows
      data.push({ category: category, value: gr.getRowCount() });
    });
```

---

**Edit** You asked how to get all categories. I don't know. In a normal database, you would have a separate table `priority` or `category` table. If that is the case, you could do something like:

```js
    var categories = [];
    var gr = new GlideRecord('priority');

    gr.query();
    while(gr.next()) {
      categories[gr.priority] = gr.category; // or name/identifier or anything else really
    }
```

This would create an object, fetch all priorities from the database, and put them there. I do not recommend getting all incidents to get the priorities, since that would probably be much more expensive.

Comment: and i think you're right. i know that my chart in this case exspects an array like the hard-coded one above and i think "now" i know how to get that data from db. my problem is, i don't really know exactly how to handle that data to form an array like the one above.
in your example i count the critical ones and so on but i put the priority levels into that var but to be honest it would be great to read them from db aswell and then put them together into an array like the mentioned one above :)

Comment: I've added something to my answer on that, but remember that I have never worked with it before, I'm just projecting my database experience onto GlideRecord